# SharePoint Online - Lookup Display multiples values in Form

Tags: json, sharepoint, lookup, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to show multiple columns in one line of data in my form via a dropdown Menu.

Right now, it's just showing the Title and I can change it. I want to format it to :

ID + " - " + Title

I saw the Display Column Formatting in JSON at the EDIT Column in SPO but I don't know if thats what I'm looking for.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try the below JSON code.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": {
  "operator": "+",
  "operands": [
      "[$ID]",
      "-",
      "[$Title]"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]